# HTML special keys showing up in post description

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView with cells of posts, in the description there are space everywhere, stuff like this everywhere:

```
&#xa0; and &nbsp;
```

and line breaks. Here is an example post:

```
Hello,


Text goes here &#xa0; and more here   and even
more &nbsp;
```

Notice the massive line break, and weird &; things and the random three or four spaces. So my question is how do I make the description look something like this:

```
Hello, Text goes here and more here and even
more. And we have room for this now because 
we don't have the line breaks.
```

It would be great if we could make it like the Mail Application description.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this solution.

```
extension String{

  func decodeEnt() -> String{
    let encodedData = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
        NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
    ]
    var attributedString = NSAttributedString()

    do
    {

     attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
    }
    catch
    {
        print("error")
    }

    return attributedString.string
}
```

//call this to convert string

```
let encodedString = "The Weeknd &#8216;King Of The Fall&#8217;" // String to convert

let foo = encodedString.decodeEnt()
```

Comment: I get this error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Please post line where it gives the error,It should work.

Comment: The let attributed string

Comment: give me the html string to convert will test on my side

Comment: I am not giving a string yet, I am getting a complier error when I put in the extension code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117525/discussion-between-harshal-bhavsar-and-zander).